# Conditionaly display fields of another node on a node page

Tags: views, nodes, entities

I am a Drupal beginner, have some CMS and PHP knowledge. I am strugling with a case which intuitively seems like a thing that had to be been solved many times.

I have these **content type**:

- `Product` with 2 fields `description` and `company`.
- `Company` with various fields but the ones that matter here are `company_intro`, `company_address`.

When I create a `product` page, I fill in the description and choose a company from a list. When I present the product page to the user, I want it to start with "company_intro" from the selected company, followed by the description and ending with the address.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to make a relation between Product and Company . to do that you have to install a reference module , [Entity References](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) or [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) .
After enabling the module (No different which one you install) you need to modify your product content type , remove your company field and add a new field of type reference to a node , then refer it to your Content type Company .

till now you have made a relation between Product and Company , now to do the rest of the job you can use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and Page Manager (included in [CTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools)) .

Check this tutorial if you are not familiar with panels : [Learning Panels and Page Manger](https://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-panels?p=1147)